# Android FTP File Download

Tags: android, ftp

So i get a NullPointerException when I try to read from a file which I downloaded from a FTP Server. My guess is that it doesn't find the file because i just know a part of the filename. Is there any way where i can open a file where I just search for a part of the Name and it takes the file which is called similar like the searching value. I'm talking about following line, where the star stands for random chars:

> InputStreamReader isr = new
>   InputStreamReader(client.retrieveFileStream("/" + "jerichTNT*"));

Can I search in that way or do i have to know the full filename with its ending?

SOLVED
Solution: I just had to type the full filename :(

Comment: You tried it i think. So you could tell.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but I kinda hoped that there could be a different sign which stands for random characters or that there would be a function. But it seems like there is no other way than knowing the full filename :/

Comment: Imagine if there were two files that started with the requested characters.... which one should be delivered? Impossible function.

Comment: You could request a file list from the directory first.

Comment: Yeah I had the same thought too "Imagine if there were two files that started with the requested characters" but It is OK now